# MongoDB with Java - Accents gone once stored

Tags: java, mongodb, utf-8, character-encoding, accent-sensitive

I have some `.txt` files which I have stored in MongoDB, but every accent once stored turns into a weird symbol.  As far as I know, MongoDB should store as UTF-8, so I have no idea why my accents are like that.

I can't use other languages and I have to keep it in Java. Any help?

Comment: It would help to see how you have the database and the connection configured

Comment: @RaulSauco where i'm supposed to look at exactly?   Especially for the first part since the problem it's on the server.  
I mean, there is any method to understand the setted configurations of the MongoDatabase (i guess you are referring to the MongoDatabase Object configurations right?)